# Searching string using grep and ignoring contents in between

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I am using below command to search string ."66688."  in all the files inside newfolder.
This is working fine.

```
grep --exclude=\*.{atr,out} -rnw '/tmp/newfolder' -e '.&quot;66688&quot;'
```

However I the number 66688 in between `.&quot;` is not constant, neither the length of the number.
Hence I want to modify this command to grep file `.&quot;WHATEVER_IN_BETWEEN_DOESNT_MATTER&quot;`

```
grep --exclude=\*.{atr,out} -rnw '/tmp/newfolder' -e '.&quot;66688&quot;'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex here:

```
grep --exclude=\*.{atr,out} -rnw '/tmp/newfolder' -e '\.&quot;.*&quot;'
```

`\.&quot;.*&quot;` will match any text that starts with `.&quot;` and ends with `&quot;`.